# Could not determine generated file paths for CoreData code generation

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

While building my project for different target I am getting this error:

> Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code
>   generation:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "No current version for model
>   at path
>   /Users/abc/Documents/Code/xyz-ios/ABC/iPhoneXMPP/SRT/Model.xcdatamodeld:"
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/abc/Documents/Code/xyz-ios/ABC/iPhoneXMPP/SRT/Model.xcdatamodeld,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=No current version for model at path
>   /Users/abc/Documents/Code/xyz-ios/ABC/iPhoneXMPP/SRT/Model.xcdatamodeld:}

Path mentioned in error is "

> /Users/abc/Documents/Code/xyz-ios/ABC/iPhoneXMPP/SRT/Model.xcdatamodeld

" but "SRT" folder is inside "Temp" folder in my folder structure. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869856/cocoa-error-260 check this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In My Case it was a result of Model.xcdatamodeld having conflicts when Merged with Remote (Source or Head). Somehow this conflict wasn't detected by GIT and slid through as Conflict Free.

Resolution: Open Model.xcdatamodeld as xml (with textEditor) and search for conflicts (>>>). Fix conflict and Save.

Answer (score 43):

Similar to shallowThought's answer, I found I had to first uncheck the target, and then re-check it, and then re-build.

Answer (score 18):

In Xcode, select your `Model.xcdatamodeld` model and tick the checkbox "Target Membership" for your new target in the Inspector.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I had renamed the directory in which my .xcdatamodel resided, which resulted in the old filename entry not being removed from my Target's `Compile Sources` phase.

All I had to do was remove the old file from the `Compile Sources` phase, by searching for `xcdatamodeld` and removing the relevant (now irrelevant...) entry in my target's `Build Phases` tab:

[image: Remove irrelevant .xcdatamodel files from the <code>Compile Sources</code> phase]

- Don't forget to do this for **ALL** the targets that contain your Core Data data model.

Once you're done, make sure that your actual current .xcdatamodeld file **is added to your target**. You do this:

**a)** By clicking on the file in Xcode's *Project Navigator* (left column -> first icon):

[image: Select your .xcdatamodeld in Xcode's Project Navigator]

**b)** And then ticking the boxes of all targets that you want this file to be a part of, in Xcode's *File Inspector* (right column -> first icon), under `Target Membership`:

[image: Tick all the targets you want your Core Data model to be a part of]

Answer (score 9):

In my case in File Selector Code Generation was Selected as Swift.
As I selected Code generation language as Objective-C.
Error Disappeared.

After selecting Objective-C

**Product > Clean**

and then **Rebuild the project.**

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just Clean and Build worked for me after adding Core Data manually (not from the start of the project).

Answer (score 3):

The answers given above are just right, but if these do not work, then:

1. Make a copy of your model and store it somewhere
2. Delete the model from Xcode
3. Add the model again to whatever folder you want to add it to

This solved my issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NSPersistentContainer, it is available from iOS 10+.
You need to change the Target > General > Deployment Info > Deployment Target to 10.0+.

Then, Product > Clean & Build. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Module Inspector > Module > Current Product Module

[image]

Clean and Build afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to build form an external drive.
Copy the project to the internal drive, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was saving a new version of `.xdatamodelid` in the pod project .xcworkspace instead of the original xcproject. Saving it in the original fix my problems.