# Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation. RestKitCoreData.xcdatamodeld

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit, core-data-migration

Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "No current version for model
>   at path /Volumes/DATA/New Data/DESKTOP/Ongoing Projects/GFIM 1.9.4
>   (32Bit)/DeliveredCode_May2
>   2/restframework/Required/Libraries/RestKit/Resources/RestKitCoreData.xcdatamodeld:"
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Volumes/DATA/New Data/DESKTOP/Ongoing
>   Projects/GFIM 1.9.4 (32Bit)/DeliveredCode_May2
>   2/restframework/Required/Libraries/RestKit/Resources/RestKitCoreData.xcdatamodeld,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=No current version for model at path
>   /Volumes/DATA/New Data/DESKTOP/Ongoing Projects/GFIM 1.9.4
>   (32Bit)/DeliveredCode_May2
>   2/restframework/Required/Libraries/RestKit/Resources/RestKitCoreData.xcdatamodeld:}

Have tried most of the things but not working. We are converting the app from 32 bit to 64 bit. `RestKit` I have downloaded from git & trying to use but it is having some kind of error which seems like I am not having the 64 bit architecture although I have downloaded `RestKit` from git by searching 64 bit. Could anybody help me to get the 64 bit or how to solve this issue.

Even though I have the RestKitCoreData.xcdatamodeld in my project folder & in compiled resources(in compile resource the path is not showing whereas other xcdatamodel is showing the path.) I could not open the RestKitCoreData.xcdatamodeld in finder. What issue is this in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not determine generated file paths for coreData code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545658/could-not-determine-generated-file-paths-for-coredata-code-generation)