# build failed Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation when merging code manually

Tags: swift, xcode, ios12

Hello  i am new with iOS development i have faced problem when merging library code with application code manually 
i have made all the solutions inside stackoverflow with no luck 
when trying to build the project the following message is showing

"Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation: No current version for model at path .xcdatamodeld: (in target 'app-Project')"

*i have made clean and rebuild
*i have made new version model by clicking on the .xcdatamodeld file and click on editor>add model version

```
    *i have added the following xml code also
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>_XCCurrentVersionName</key>
        <string>app-Project.xcdatamodel</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

any idea what else i can do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not determine generated file paths for CoreData code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545658/could-not-determine-generated-file-paths-for-coredata-code-generation)

Comment: i have tried all the solutions there but non of them worked

Comment: Please share some code relevant to your problem