# Xcode 12: error: Could not load code generator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

I am getting this error, when I am trying to build project with Xcode 12. Can anyone please help?
Thanks.

> error: Could not load code generator
> [image]

Comment: seem there are different causes for this kind of error, failing to generate code for core data model. Did you try `shift` + `cmd` + `k` to clean the building cache and building the project again?  or did you try to open `DBLogicPuzzle.xcdatamodeld` as XML in `textEdit` to see if there is conflict or something wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545658/could-not-determine-generated-file-paths-for-coredata-code-generation/43382624

Comment: Thx @RYZheng. Yes, I tried clean, build, and checked ".xcdatamodeld" file, all correct, there are no conflicts.

Comment: If you have two Xcode, try to move both of them into the Application folder, then clean and build again.

Comment: @ThanveerAhammed thanks for answer, but after after xcdode update this issue solved.